# how can i get log about rule that i configured in firewall on the VPC Firewall section( denied icmp request to gcp instance) are appening?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging, firewall, icmp

I know that the firewall logs of gcp don't show hit of icmp request that denied permission to an instance of vm on gcp.
How i can see this rule that works with api of gcp or with other way that you know?

Comment: Please improve your question to clearly state the problem. What does this sentence mean? **How i can see this rule that works with api of gcp or with other way that you know?**

Comment: It means that i want to know when the rule that i do on in the firewall of the instance(deny all icmp request ,ping...) are appening...

Comment: Your sentence grammar is confusing. There are two types of firewalls commonly used in Google Cloud. The VPC Firewall and the OS firewall. Which are you referring to? Rewrite your question to clearly state the problem.

Comment: It's on the vpc firewall...